# Why does the Github network graph not show old branshes?

Tags: git, github, graph, branching-and-merging

I am fairly new to Github, and I am trying to figure out the best workflow for using Github with my projects. I found a workflow on [this page](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow) that I liked and that would fit well together my project!

I have created a `development` branch from the `master` branch. And from the `development` branch i created a new branch for an issue called `iss13`. Once i was done fixing issue #13 I merged `iss13` back into the `development` branch. After the merge was successful i deleted the `iss13` branch.

But when I go to look at the network graph the `iss13` "pipe" is gone from the graph. Is this supposed to happen? Or am I not using the workflow correctly? I would like to see all the earlier merges for better control.

Here is a picture of what I see and what i would like to see:

[image: Here is a picture of what I see and what i would like to see]

The graph from the workflow I am trying to achieve:

[image: The graph from the workflow I am trying to achieve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the development branch in blue had no new commit since the creation of the `iss13` branch, the `development` branch was fast-forwarded to match the last commit of `iss13`.

[image: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/git-branches#!merge]

To force to create a "merge" commit between `development` and `iss13`, you can use the `--no-ff` option of `git merge/pull` to create a commit with the top commit of the `development` branch and the top commit of the `iss13` branch as ancestors.